# logstash elastic search date output is different

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

my system audit log contains the date format like created_at":1422765535789, so, the elastic search output also displays the date as same style. however, I would like convert and print this 1422765535789 to unix style date format.

I've used this format in syslog file (as suggested by another question thread) . but I am not getting the above value to unix style Date format
     date {
          match => ["created_at", "UNIX_MS"]
        }

Hi, I've updated the code in the syslog , however, I am getting the created_at still output to elastic search page on same format like 1422765535789 , please find the modified code

```
input {
        stdin {

        }
}


filter {
        grok {
        match => [ "message", "%{NUMBER:created_at}"
        ]
     }
if [message] =~ /^created_at/ {

        date {
                match => [ "created_at" , "UNIX_MS" ]
        }
        ruby {
            code => "
                    event['created_at'] =     Time.at(event['created_at']/1000);
            "
        }
   }
}
output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `date` filter is used to update the `@timestamp` field value.

```
input {
    stdin {

    }
}

filter {
    grok {
            match => [ "message", "%{NUMBER:created_at:int}"
                    ]
    }
    if "_grokparsefailure" not in [tags]
    {
            date {
                    match => [ "created_at" , "UNIX_MS" ]
            }
            ruby {
                    code => "
                            event['created_at'] = Time.at(event['created_at']/1000);
                    "
            }
    }
}

output
{
    stdout {
            codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

Here is my config. When I input `1422765535789`, it can parse the value and update the `@timestamp` field value.

The output is

```
{
       "message" => "1422765535789",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2015-02-01T04:38:55.789Z",
          "host" => "ABC",
    "created_at" => "2015-02-01T12:38:55.000+08:00"
}
```

You can found the value of `@timestamp` is same with `created_at`. 
And, the `ruby` filter is used to convert the `created_at` to UTC format.

FYI.

Comment: hi thanks for your help, I used above code in my syslog, however I am getting this error while running the logstash  error is  ://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}
Exception in filterworker {"exception"=>#<NoMethodError: undefined method `/' for "35":String>, "backtrace"=>["(ruby filter code):2:in `register'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'", "/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/filters/ruby.rb:38:in `filter'", "(eval):63:in `initialize'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'", "/logstash/logstash-1.4.2/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:262:in `filter'",

Comment: The error log means the created_at is not exist a timestamp. So, you can add a if to make sure the created_at field have a valid timestamp value

Comment: hi, please find my updated code in my question. I am still getting the same format in log stash UI page like 1422765535789 , thank you

Comment: Sorry about that. I have update the answer. First, parse the create_at value and convert to integer. Then, make sure the grok parse success. Last, convert to the time format you want.

Comment: thank you much. I am getting the created_at converted time stamp now.